# multi gpu llm inference error: index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I tried to load any LLM (for example `mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2`). When I run this code on one gpu, it works well. However when I tried to run it on multiple devices (rtx6000, CUDA Version: 12.1) I got this error:

```
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/IndexKernel.cu:93: operator(): block: [1,0,0], thread: [31,0,0] Assertion `index >= -sizes[i] && index < sizes[i] && "index out of bounds"` failed.

cos = cos[position_ids].unsqueeze(unsqueeze_dim)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

Here is my code:

```
import torch
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from tqdm import tqdm
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig, pipeline, AutoModelForCausalLM
import os

max_length = 2048
model_id = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id,,
                                          model_max_length=max_length)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, trust_remote_code=True,
                                             device_map='auto').eval()
model.config.pad_token_id = tokenizer.pad_token_id

text = "how much is 1+1?"

inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)
outputs = model(**inputs)
```

When I remove `device_map`, it runs on one gpu and works well.

I'm using:
`torch==2.2.1, tokenizers==0.15.1, transformers==4.38.1, accelerate==0.26.1`

How can I solve this error? Thanks.